# How to repair scratches by utility knife on wooden dinner table?

Tags: repair, wood, wooden-furniture

The wood is the fake kind, not actual wood, found in cheap furnture. The scratches were made by a cutter knife.

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Is it plastic? Plastic laminate? Something else? Actually, in any case, the answer is "you don't". Wood can be sanded, filled, and refinished. Those other things can't. Cheap is cheap for a reason.

Comment: Its wood, not plastic, looks shiny. The scratch is not deep, but it can be felt by touching it.

Comment: You said, "the wood is the fake kind, not actual wood". Then you said, "it's wood". You can imagine the conundrum we're in. :)

Comment: get a table cloth

Comment: rubbing with toothpaste on a tennis ball will reduce the visibility of the refracting ruffled gouge edges.

Comment: you can try a wood filler stick/pencil. They sell them at the box store in a variety of shades to try to match your color.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how deep the scratch is. 
Before more typing, why not just place a table cloth over the scratch since it is what you said?
To "fix" finishing on wood furniture requires techniques, and costs on materials.
Is it worth the fixing? looked like it's all the way across edges.

Answer (score 0):

If the surface is real wood you can sand the marks out then refinish the surface.  If fake wood you can rough the surface and overlay with a laminate. Trim edge with flush trim router bit.